# UIFont is not convertible error

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uifont

I just converted my swift 2.3 code to 3.0,But suddenly UILabel view shows an error when I try to change the font type. Here is the error. It shows that `(name: String, size: CGFloat)-> UIFont is not convertible to (name: String, size: CGFloat)-> UIFont?` why can't I change Font type ? I've cleaned and built the project but show same error. Here is the UILabel

```
        let placeholder = UILabel()
        placeholder.bounds = self.tableView.bounds
        placeholder.textAlignment = .Center
        placeholder.textColor = UIColor(red: 230.0/255.0, green: 230.0/255.0, blue: 230.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        placeholder.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 15.0)
        placeholder.text = "No Events"
        self.tableView.backgroundView = placeholder
```

Here is the error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
placeholder.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 15.0)
```

you should try writing this:

```
placeholder.font = UIFont.init(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 15)
```

for more information see [this](https://github.com/icanzilb/SwiftSpinner/issues/65)

Comment: Thank you ! It's working, But why can't I write UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 15.0) ? why should I write init() ?

Comment: @ChathurangaSilva - It's an issue with the failable initializer update in Swift